# Temporarily loading and unloading packages in an R function

Tags: r, namespaces, package

I am writing a function that will take the name of an installed package and return a data frame listing all the data frames available in that package along with the number and types of variables in those data frames.

In order to do this, I need to `require` the package temporarily so I can access its data sets. The problem I have is that requiring a package also introduces a whole lot of extra stuff into the search path and the loaded namespaces beyond just the package in question. I want my function to tidy up after itself, but I can't find a good way to `detach` everything that got imported when the package was required. In particular, `detach` seems to detach only the package, but not any of the other imported stuff.

Any advice?

Comment: You can access a package's exported objects (including datasets) with `::`. Eg `MASS::Insurance`

Comment: Right, but the package I'm writing won't know in advance what data sets are available in the requested package. I need to attach the requested package before I'll know which data sets are available in that package.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what IDE you are workign with but many of them have "tab-completion". If I type :....... `?unload` at my console and hit `<tab>` I immmediately see `??unloadNamespace` ... so that would be a reasonable function to investigate. You should first look at:

```
     ?unloadNamespace
```

... and then decide if that is sufficient. There is also the `detach` function that has a link to its associated help page in that help page.

Comment: Neither `detach` nor `unloadNamespace` do what I'm requesting.